# Running gui docker container (based on ubuntu) in Windows Docker Desktop is extremely lagging

Tags: windows, docker, user-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lag

i have a docker container based on ubuntu:20.04 with running qtcreator. I tested this container in Ubuntu host machine and its work perfectly and fast.

But with windows docker desktop there is extremely lagging.. for XServer i use VcSrv from https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/.

Actually, any gui docker app works same way (i tried xeyes and firefox apps, they are lagging too approximately the same - the program window does not keep up with the user's actions: resize window, scroll, typing, etc)
[gif with lagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DumPE.gif)

to fix this problem i tried:

1. with and without wsl2 based engine
   [wsl2 based engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O8uY.png)
2. wsl integration (and without it)
   [wsl integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjLuq.png)
3. create .wslconfig with maximum resource priority to wsl
4. disable hyper-v

nothing works.

Maybe I don't understand something and this issue is somehow very easily solved.
Please tell me how to significantly speed up the response of such an application running in a linux container on a windows host machine